# Chaining array matches in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, indexing

This seems like a fairly complicated task. Let me explain the scenario with small examples.

Consider 5 arrays `a1`, `a2`, `a3`, `a4`, and `a5`. These arrays are not important, I'm mentioning them for the sake of completeness. Consider 4 matches arrays `m1`, `m2`, `m3`, `m4` of sizes `10`, `9`, `11` and `10`. Each array basically tells you which element of the first array `a<i>` matched with second `a<i+1>`.

Eg. if `m1 = [-1, 0, 2, -1, 3, 8, 7, -1, 9, 5]`
It means that the 0<sup>th</sup> element of `a1` does not have a match, the 1<sup>st</sup> of `a1` matches with the 0<sup>th</sup> element of `a2` and the 2<sup>nd</sup> element of `a1` matches with the 2<sup>nd</sup> element of `a2`.

Thus, the size of `m1` = size of `a1` and size of `m2` = size of `a2` etc.

Similarly, if  `m2 = [-1, 0, 2, 6, 3, 8, 7, -1, 9, 5]`
It establishes the correspondent matches between `a2` and `a3`.

Here is my question. Is it possible to find out which element from `a1` corresponds to elements in `a3`? My final goal is to establish this correspondence between `a1` and `a5`.

For the `a1` to `a3`, my matched new array will be `m = [-1, -1, 2, -1, 6, 9, -1, -1, 5, 8]` . To explain how I get this `m` array, for eg. `m[4] = m2[m1[4]]`.

What is the most  efficient way to do this?

A few notes:

1. The `-1` is merely an indicator to represent that there is no
   match and can be replaced with anything that would make the problem
   easier.
2. The biggest problem I face is that
   `m2[m1[7]]` should ideally be `-1` since `m1[7]` is
   `-1`, however, due to Python/numpy indexing rules, `m2[-1]`
   will be taken as the last element of `m2`, which is not
   desirable in this case
3. This is just a toy example and my arrays and matches arrays will be of sizes ~2000 elements.

If anyone is interested in its application, or if extra information would help, this pertains to images feature matching. Using `opencv` I extract `orb` features and perform feature matches between three images I<sub>1</sub>, I<sub>2</sub> and I<sub>3</sub>. I have correspondences between I<sub>1</sub>-I<sub>2</sub> and I<sub>2</sub>-I<sub>3</sub> and would like to compute the matches between I<sub>1</sub>-I<sub>3</sub> indirectly using the above two correspondences.

Comment: You should provide samples of all of your arrays along with the expected output from each step.

Comment: It is not entirely defined by `m1, m2...` for example for `a1 = [0, 1], a2 = [1, 2], a3 = [0, 1]: m1 = [-1, 0], m2=[1, -1]; m13 = [0, 1]` but `a1 = [9, 1], a2 = [1, 2], a3 = [0, 1]: m1 = [-1, 0], m2=[1, -1]; m13 = [-1, 1]`

Comment: Hey @Chris, I have given the example with ```m1```, ```m2``` and my expected output as ```m```. If I understand how to do it for 2 consecutive matches, I can always extrapolate it to further matches in the chain

Comment: @V.Ayrat It is best to assume ```a1```, ```a2``` etc. as irrelevant to this problem since I am only concerned with the matched arrays ```m1```, ```m2``` etc. The ```a``` arrays are more or less independently obtained.

Comment: One way to eliminate the problem in your second point is that append all matrices by one element and keep them as `-1`. Thus in `m2[m1[7]]`, `m1[7]` will be `-1` and `m2[-1]` will be `-1` again as we have added `-1` at the last position.

Comment: @RahulKedia hmm that sounds feasible. Can you provide a vectorized code if possible?

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could do is to entend each array m1, m2, .... by one value.
Then replace that extra value and '-1' by the (length-1) of next array m2, m3, ... respectively.

But, in the last array, change '-1' to 'no match' (or any other value you prefer), and append the same value.

```
m1 = [-1, 0, 2, -1, 3, 8, 7, -1, 9, 5]
m2 = [-1, 0, 2, 6, 3, 8, 7, -1, 9, 5]

m_list = [m1, m2]

for i in range(len(m_list)-1):
    m_list[i] = [len(m_list[i+1]) if x==-1 else x for x in m_list[i]]
    m_list[i].append(len(m_list[i+1]))
m_list[len(m_list)-1] = ['no match' if x==-1 else x for x in m_list[len(m_list)-1]]
m_list[len(m_list)-1].append('no match')

m1, m2 = m_list
```

Now if you run `m2[m1[7]]`, your output will be `'no match'`.

> Note : The m1, m2, .... you will get will have one extra length. So if
> you are using it somewhere else, be careful for any errors.